# Kalman filter usage to predict projectile trajectory that is facing camera

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, kinect, kalman-filter, projectile

I'm trying to predict where thrown object will hit a ground, so I figure I need to predict it's path using Kalman filter to estimate future states of the projectile.
The camera I'm using is Kinect v1,  I'm using the depth camera to track the object so I get (X,Y,Z) points each 4 frames, It gives me about 5 to 8 points, this [video shows my tracked object](https://i.imgur.com/t0FQhvM.mp4), I'm trying to achieve similar results to [this one](https://i.imgur.com/ClvHSR4.mp4).

Is Kalman filter the way to go?, if so, how do I estimate more than one future state since I want to get the future path of the projectile?.

Thank you.